# Difference in Checksum Values

Tags: sha1

I am calculating  the checksum of .txt files on AIX and Linux environments.Different hash values are coming on both platforms for the same file.  but when iam doing the same for another file types(.doc,.docx,.xlsx,.zip,.Tar) , value is same on both environments. iam using SHA1 to determine the cksum
Please any one help with this..

BR,
Srikanth

Comment: How did you transfer the files?

Comment: I am uploading the files to Cloud server and downloading to host system via an automation program. i can refer it as Offshore and Onshore activity

Comment: Speculation: the system (either the client, or the storage on the cloud) could be detecting the files as text files, and trying to transform them to try to match configuration regarding line endings, or perhaps it is adding [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to prevent problems with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), or even detecting a BOM and changing it to the target platform. Futhermore, it could force an encoding, convert whitespace, or ensure a new line at the end of the file. Try using some hex editor to compare them that way.

Comment: Thanks Theraot...yeah CRLF are the reasons for this.